# SDL2 draw and fill shapes

Tags: c++, sdl-2

How can I draw different shapes (other than rectangle and line) and fill them using SDL2 in C++? I tried using SDL2_gfx, but I couldn't get SDL2_gfx compiled, so I couldn't try it. I found a compiled SDL_gfx but since I'm using renderer not surfaces I can't use it. Drawing polygons is simple, I can just calculate the point and draw lines, but how do I fill them? And how do I draw circle?

If anyone has a compiled SDL2_gfx (same way like SDL2_ttf and SDL2_image) then maybe you could send it to me?

Comment: You said that a compiled version of SDL2_gfx had not worked for you. Why do you think that if someone else compiled it, it would work?

Comment: I said i couldn't compile the SDL2_gfx. That means i couldn't try SDL2_gfx. But thanks I'll fix my post, since it seems bit too ambiguous

Comment: To [draw a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm). To fill shapes, doing it per pixel is possible but very inefficient. You're better off spending time compiling SDL2_gfx and getting help with the errors.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I overlooked that '2'.

Comment: @coyotte508 I have taken a look into SDL2_gfx and i can say that its filling algorithm is per pixel. Its just the case of finding the most efficient way to do it per pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fill a polygon a quick google search gives an efficient algorithm [here](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill/). Or copying the way SDL2_gfx does it is possible, as you have access to the sources?

For drawing a circle, there is [the Midpoint Circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) with even some code given:

```
void DrawCircle(int x0, int y0, int radius)
{
    int x = 0, y = radius;
    int dp = 1 - radius;
    do
    {
        if (dp < 0)
            dp = dp + 2 * (++x) + 3;
        else
            dp = dp + 2 * (++x) - 2 * (--y) + 5;

        putpixel(x0 + x, y0 + y, 15);     //For the 8 octants
        putpixel(x0 - x, y0 + y, 15);
        putpixel(x0 + x, y0 - y, 15);
        putpixel(x0 - x, y0 - y, 15);
        putpixel(x0 + y, y0 + x, 15);
        putpixel(x0 - y, y0 + x, 15);
        putpixel(x0 + y, y0 - x, 15);
        putpixel(x0 - y, y0 - x, 15);

    } while (x < y);
}
```

But what should really be done is seek help in solving the problem of compiling SDL2_gfx. Worst comes to worst, can't you just put the source files of SDL2_gfx in your project directly? It's only four files that you can put in a subfolder of your project.

Comment: I will probably put source files under my project. And all of SDL2 sourcecode i open source so i you go on the home page of SDL or SDL-gfx or what ever, you'll find the sourcodes there and you can look at the code. For curiosity sake i looked into SDL2 fill rect function, but in the end i didn't understand what is going on. I got lost somewhere between the assembly part and tons of macros.